# Completely destroy object and free memory in particular case (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, garbage-collection

I'm writing a program that can load some user modules. My main program has a list of objects that are shared between the program and the user modules. Now the deal is that theses objects may be removed/added from the list. They are dynamic.

In my own program I can make sure all the reference to the removed item are set to null and clean all listener. (is that the correct way to allow garbage collector to process by the way ?).

The problem is that the user modules may do whatever they want with the removed object. They can add listerners, keep reference to it, etc. How do I can free the memory in this case ? After a long time running of my program and many adding / removing of these objects I could lead to a memory leak ...

Thanks in advances.